# Silverlight 3 security and Authentication mechanism

Tags: silverlight, security

I am creating a Silverlight 3 application for which i am designing the security block. I already have an existent ASP.NET authentication module that i will reuse in the WCF security service(which will be like a wrapper and this will be called from Silverlight). My goal is to use SSL for the transport security. Also i would want this to be scalable as i don't want to query the DBMS for each authentication service call.

Any pointers on best design approaches.

Thank you. Anjan

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it done in ASP.Net then you might want to take a look at [.NET RIA Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices). RIA Services allows you to hook into the ASP.Net authentication right inside of Silverlight. Brada has written about this and has a [post on RIA Services Authentication here](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/22/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-6-poco-and-authentication-provider.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, but i dont want to hit the Database each time as i would want my scale up. I would like to know if there is a DB call each time the authentication is fired.

Comment: There is a DB call the first time the user is authenticated (no way around that), but after that there wouldn't be any more calls. Forms Authentication in ASP.Net sets an authentication cookie. As long as the cookie is valid and hasn't expired no database calls will be made.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what benefits do RIA give me. I did go through the samples but i did not arrive at a conclusion where i can say that RIA gives me some capabilities string enough to use them. Thoughts?